# First installation like a breeze - reinstallation nothing but woes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I own a MSI GS60 that has Intel Graphics and an nVidia GTX 860M graphic cards, a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HD.

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on it without any problems. I totally loved it.

Then I had the idea of having the 128GB SSD being replaced with my spare Crucial 512 GB. Unfortenately that couldn't be done because the internal SSD is mSata while the Crucial isn't.

The guys that I asked to do this had already cleared the Ubuntu partition because they needed to clone the original drive. Stupid me, I thought cloning would mean a 1:1 copy of the drive.

Anyway, I thought that wouldn't matter as I could simply do a reinstall. Yeah for Linux I thought.

But, for some reason I cannot get it back to working again.

When I shutdown Ubuntu hangs. This happens with the 15.03 live cd, with the 14.0 live CD, with the 15.04 installation, with a 14.04 installation.

I've searched this forum high and low and tried different tricks that I found.

I've replaced the drivers with the drivers from the nVidia website, didn't solve anything. I've edited the EFI boot entries cause I thought there might be something in that that would mess up something. I've reinstalled the factory Windows 8 image to start with a clean slate. I've asked for help on a local Ubuntu forum, but the only advise was to use 14.04, which I tried but no difference. Also, I had 15.04 on it earlier which worked fine.

I've edited the Grub lines to remove the quiet and splash options. Then it seems to wait for 3 minutes on some udev thing. I don't know what.

When I tried to boot it before writing this message it didn't seem to boot at all.

I would really like to switch to Ubuntu again for my development environment, but at this time I really don't have a clue why this installation is so troublesome. As far as I know it is exactly the same hardware as it was, so it should install just as easily.

Comment: I notice that the shutdown issue exists when the GPU is the Intel Haswell onboard, and, I have to check when the GPU is the nVidia, but the BIOS is set to fast boot.